# Using CustomStringConvertible in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, customstringconvertible

I've declared the following:

```
class Song: CustomStringConvertible {
    let title: String
    let artist: String

    init(title: String, artist: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(title) \(artist)"
    }
}

var songs = [
    Song(title: "Song Title 3", artist: "Song Author 3"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 2", artist: "Song Author 2"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 1", artist: "Song Author 1")
]
```

I want to enter this information into a `UITableView`, specifically at the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Such as this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel = //the song title from the CustomStringConvertible[indexPath.row]
    cell.artistLabel = //the author title from the CustomStringConvertible[indexPath.row]
}
```

How would I do this? I can't figure it out.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your Controller must implement UITableViewDataSource.
Then,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel?.text = songs[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel?.text =songs[indexPath.row].artiste
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be conflating CustomStringConvertible with some other design patterns. First, an answer:

```
// You have some container class with your tableView methods
class YourTableViewControllerClass: UIViewController {

    // You should probably maintain your songs array in here, making it global is a little risky

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell : LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell

        // Get the song at the row
        let cellSong = songs[indexPath.row]

        // Use the song
        cell.titleLabel.text = cellSong.title
        cell.artistLabel.text = cellSong.artist
    }
}
```

Because the cell's title/artist are already public strings, you can just use them as you need. CustomStringConvertible will allow you to use *the actual object itself* as a String. So, in your case, you could have a `song` and call `song.description` and it would print out "title artist". But if you want to use the song's `title` and `artist`, you should just call `song.title` and `song.artist`. [Here's the documentation on that protocol.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

Also, as I wrote above, try moving your `songs` array into your ViewController. And maybe consider using `struct`s instead of `class`s for your `Song` type.